# How to change publisher name of already published extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to change my publisher name in VScode marketplace.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

(Late reply) Did you have a look at this [VS Code Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3670)? Basically they say they *could* technically transfer the ownership, but still there are some consequences for your extension users due to a different ID.

The other suggested option is to openly create a new extension under the new publisher, and deprecate the former one.

Specifically, [this is](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3670#issuecomment-191767639) the main comment:

> We can technically transfer ownership of an extension, but just be aware that moving the extension under a different publisher will change the extension’s fully-qualified identifier. This could impact clients, like VS Code, that try to look up the extension by its old ID.
>
> If the extension doesn’t have a lot of downloads, it might be easier to just remove from the old publisher and re-publish under the new publisher.
>
> Following is an example shared by Erich Gamma where a change publisher was done by creating a new extension under the new publisher and deprecating the old one.

(Sadly the referenced example is gone)

HTH