# Creating extensions - Publisher display name

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to change only the display name of the publisher?
A similar question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745643/how-to-change-publisher-name-of-already-published-extension), but I don't want to move the extension to an other publisher id.
I created an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csaar95.oregator), but it displays my "username", it would be great, if it's possible to display the company name I'm working for (for instance "Microsoft" extensions).
I already tried to change the name in the `package.json` (`__metadata`), but it only works while debugging. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this possible. You just need to go to he [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) and press the button *Publish extensions* (in the top right corner). After you logged in you should see your extensions. Now switch to the *Details* tab where you can change the *Name* field.

Comment: Thanks!
Am I right, if I want to publish under my personal name I have to create a new publisher?

Comment: If you want the publisher ID to be your real name you have to create a new publisher.